# How to decide what view should be on top in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

So i have a problem that i know how to solve but not in ann efficient/fast way. Look at this example that i have right now:

[image]

So I had made all the outlets before I decided that I need a background image. You can see that I marked them but they are under the `UIImage`. I can solve this by first removing the image and dragging all the views to another view controller then adding the `UIImage` and putting the views back on the ImageView but this is time consuming as I have other view controllers. Is there another way to move views up/down?

Comment: Drag the `Image View` in the left view up so that it is listed before the four marked items. The order in the list reflects the actual positional order in the view.

Comment: Lol thank you it worked! @luk2302

Comment: @RohitPradhan no, it has nothing to do with being anyones `superView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the views as being listed in the order they are placed on top of others. You start at the top of the list, adding views, and then add the ones next on the list on top, one a time. That's how I remember the ordering.

As Luk2302 says, you can simply drag your views around inside your storyboard to change their order.

Note that there is also an "arrange" sub-menu in the editor menu for IB. You could select your background image, then pick `editor>arrange>send to back` to move the background view to the back of the stack of views.

P.S.: Don't call them outlets. They are views. Views can be linked to your code using `IBOutlets`, but they don't have to be. Plus other non-view objects like constraints can also be linked to your code with `IBOutlets`

Comment: Great explanation as usual. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple.what you have to do is simply drag you `imageview` to the top of the view(then it becomes the first `IBOutlet` you added). I have added some images, then it will easy to understand.

this is your situation

[image]

this is the solution(drag it to the top of the view)

[image]

then your other `IBOutlets` come to the front like this

[image]